# Take the product of rows in a matrix by group in R

Tags: r, performance, matrix

I'm looking for a way to do essentially what the [`rowsum`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/rowsum) function does, except take the product instead of the sum.

Let's say I have the matrix `a` and a vector of grouping IDs `group`:

```
a <- matrix(seq(12), ncol = 2)
group <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
```

I can get the sums of each row by group using `rowsum(a, group)`:

```
rowsum(a, group)
```

```
  [,1] [,2]
1    3   15
2    7   19
3   11   23
```

How could I get the *product* of each row by group, which would give:

```
  [,1] [,2]
1    2   56
2   12   90 
3   30  132
```

Answer (score 4):

For values of `a > 0`, you could use

```r
exp(rowsum(log(a), group))

#>    [,1] [,2]
#> 1    2   56
#> 2   12   90
#> 3   30  132
```

This is solution based on

```r
a * b = exp(log(a * b)) = exp(log(a) + log(b))
```

Comment: Oooo, very clever. I think this does it. Someone should write a `rowprod` function that does exactly this.

Comment: Brilliant solution, + 1!

Comment: Perhaps a word of caution if there are any values `<= 0`

Comment: @Henrik You are totally right. I didn't thought of that case.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `apply` + `tapply` + `prod`

```
> apply(a, 2, tapply, group, prod)
  [,1] [,2]
1    2   56
2   12   90
3   30  132
```

Answer (score 2):

In `base R`, `aggregate` should work as well

```
aggregate(a, list(group), FUN = prod)[-1]
  V1  V2
1  2  56
2 12  90
3 30 132
```

---

Or another option is `fprod` from `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
fprod(a, g = group)
  [,1] [,2]
1    2   56
2   12   90
3   30  132
```

Comment: Fabulous `aggregate` solution, simplify thins a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the same results doing the product of the rows

```r
a <- matrix(seq(12), ncol = 2)
group <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)

rowsum(a, group)
#>   [,1] [,2]
#> 1    3   15
#> 2    7   19
#> 3   11   23

matrixStats::rowProds(a,group)
#> [1]  7  7 16 16 27 27
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure if the `matrixStats::rowProds` function does the same thing as what I described. Looks like it's taking the product across each column rather than each row.